# Can the restricted composition $\Delta_A$ be different from $\Delta$ where $A\subset E$ and $\Delta$ is defined on $E$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, examples-counterexamples

In *New Structures from Old* in *Seth Werner*'s *Modern Algebra*, the author discusses the closure of a composition  $\Delta$ on a set $E$ in $A\subset E:$

> Let $\Delta$ be a composition on $E\,.$ A subset $A$ of $E$ is **stable** for $\Delta,$ or closed under $\Delta,$  if $x\Delta y\in A$ for all $x, y\in A\,.$
>
> If $A$ is stable for a composition $\Delta$ on $E,$ we shall denote the restriction of $\Delta$ to $A\times A$ by $\Delta_A$ when it is necessary to emphasize that it is not the same as the given composition on $E\,.$

He then discusses few examples like the set of integral multiples of a positive integer $m$ is stable for the addition and multiplication composition in $\mathbb Z$; any subset of $\mathbb N$ is stable for the composition $\boldsymbol\vee$ defined on $\mathbb N$ as $x\boldsymbol \vee y~=~\textrm{max}\{x,y\}\,.$

So,  all the restricted compositions in the examples above are basically the same composition as defined for the superset viz. $\Delta_A ~=~ \Delta$  (although the domains and ranges are different.)

However, is it possible that the restricted composition $\Delta_A$ is different from $\Delta$ viz. $\Delta_E\ne \Delta$?

Is there any example for such case if it is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, the very *definition* of the restricted composition $\Delta_A$ is that $\Delta_A(a,b)=\Delta(a,b)$ for each $a,b\in A$.  That is what the phrase "we shall denote the restriction of $\Delta$ to $A\times A$ by $\Delta_A$"  means.  If $f$ is a function on a set $X$ and $Y\subseteq X$, the restriction of $f$ to $Y$ is the function $g$ on $Y$ defined by $g(y)=f(y)$ for each $y\in Y$.  In this case $X=E\times E$, $f=\Delta$, and $Y=A\times A$.  So "the restriction of $\Delta$ to $A\times A$" refers to the function $\Delta_A(a,b)=\Delta(a,b)$ with domain $A\times A$.

(Note that it's not really correct to write $\Delta_A=\Delta$, since they are not the same function since they have different domain.  What is true is that these two functions take the same values at all points where both of them are defined.)

Comment: Yes, I do agree that the restriction $\Delta_A ~=~ \Delta$where the domain would be $A\times A\,.$ But it is not necessary that the values of the restriction $\Delta_A$ maps the element back to $A$ which is what we need for $\Delta_A$ to be composition on $A$ viz. $\Delta_A: A\times A\mapsto A\,.$ In the above examples mentioned,the restriction $\Delta_A$ is a composition as it brings the value back to the required set and $\Delta_A~=~ \Delta$ (strictly speaking, they aren't same). So, does that mean for the restriction to be a composition, $\Delta_A$ has to be different from $\Delta$ [contd.]

Comment: after-all as though the restriction $\Delta_A ~=~ \Delta$ and it maps from $A\times A,$ it need not be mapping it back to $A$?  To be the restriction of $\Delta$, the domain gets reduced to $A\times A$ but we are not talking about the range, it basically remains $\Delta$ which now works from $A\times A$; for the restriction to be a composition, the range has to be $A;$ does $\Delta_A~=~ \Delta$ always guarantee that? If not, then won't it be $\Delta_A$ has to be different for it to be a composition?

Comment: I don't know what "for the restriction to be a composition, $\Delta_A$ has to be different from $\Delta$" means.  If you look at the quote in your question, it defines $\Delta_A$ **only when** $A$ is stable for $\Delta$, in which case $\Delta_A$ gives a composition on $A$.  If $A$ is not stable for $\Delta$, there is no canonical way to get a composition on $A$ from $\Delta$.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the reply; lesson revoked again: be attentive and read again between the lines of the book.